# Matlab can not read the socket for the second time

Tags: matlab, sockets

I want to communicate between two programs. MATLAB is able to read the socket once but when it tries to read it again, I get the following warning

> Warning: Unsuccessful read: A timeout occurred before the Terminator was reached.

**Matlab code:**

```
clc
clear all
while(1)
    clear tcpipServer
    tcpipServer = tcpip('127.0.0.1', 55000, 'NetworkRole', 'Server');
    set(tcpipServer, 'Timeout', 30);
    fopen(tcpipServer);
    rawData = fgetl(tcpipServer);
    fclose(tcpipServer);
end
```

The data which is sent to Matlab is defined as string and the value is "y\n".
The problem is that I only receive "y\n" once.
The other side connected to the socket is the Unity game engine. I think the code in the unity is correct because I tested that by c# windows app and I can get the value as long as program is running.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Does it matter that you destroy and recreate the socket each time you go through the loop? I would imagine if you had Unity send a message to MATLAB via the socket, that message wouldn't exist upon establishing a new connection. Also maybe try `fread` rather than `fgetl`.

Comment: before asking this question I try all that you mentioned, fread and not destroying socket.

Comment: Do you have the Unity code that is at the other end of this socket? Are you sure that it's rebroadcasting a message?

Comment: fortunately i found what was the problem. actually Matlab is very low at accepting the socket or opening the socket. at the unity side i used a delay before writing socket. it means when i open the connection i should wait for about 0.2 second and after that write it. thank you.

Comment: It may be beneficial to add that information (along with a code sample) as an answer to this question in case other people have this issue in the future.

Comment: <p>check this stackoverflow link and help please.....<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785948/reading-data-from-ur5-robots-tcp-ip-socket-with-matlab-as-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution i found.

**Matlab code:**

```
clc
clear all
%% server  initialization
tcpipServer = tcpip('127.0.0.1',55000,'NetworkRole','Server');
set(tcpipServer,'Timeout',30);
while(1)

%% server code: listening for incoming requests

fopen(tcpipServer);
%rawData = fread(tcpipServer,1,'char');
rawData = fgetl(tcpipServer)
extractedData=str2double(strsplit(rawData,'-'))

fclose(tcpipServer);
```

**Unity C# code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


public class server : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    TcpListener listener;
    String msg;
    StreamWriter theWriter1;
    internal Boolean socketReady = false;
    TcpClient mySocket;
    NetworkStream theStream;
    StreamWriter theWriter;
    StreamReader theReader;
    String Host = "localhost";
    Int32 Port = 55000;
    bool firstTimeRun=true;

    void Start () {

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        setupSocket ();
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0))
            {
            setupSocket ();

            }
    }
    public void setupSocket() {
        try {
            TcpClient mySocket1;
            NetworkStream theStream1;
            //StreamWriter theWriter1;
            mySocket1 = new TcpClient(Host, Port);
            theStream1 = mySocket1.GetStream();
            theWriter1 = new StreamWriter(theStream1);
            Invoke("write", 0.2f);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.Log("Socket error: " + e);
        }
    }
    void write()
    {
        float x;float y;
        x = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform.position.x;
        y=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform.position.y;
        theWriter1.Write(x+"-"+y+"\n");
        theWriter1.Flush();

    }
```

The reason I used "\n" is using **fgetl** function in Matlab code. if you want to make the code more functional use delay along with Asynchronous tasks in Unity. for those wandering why using delay is required, see the comments under question.